# Are Tux Droids still functional?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, usb

Are [Tux droids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux_Droid) still functional? 
Will they work with Ubuntu 16.04 or later?
Where to get the installation for them?

Comment: The website seems defunct / hijacked by Chinese .. so probably not.